# Unable to execute update using JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to update a table using JpaRepository, below is my code

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Query(value = "update session set terminatedOn = ?1 where topicName = ?2 and createdBy=?3", nativeQuery = true)
Sessions stopSession(LocalDateTime terminatedOn, String topicName, String createdBy );
```

in the logs, I can see the below generated query

```
Hibernate: update session set terminatedOn = ? where topicName = ? and createdBy=?
```

but my server is throwing an error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
```

Comment: Try adding `@Modifying` to your method. That should tell hibernate to call `executeUpdate` instead

Comment: with @Modifying, am unable to create the bean

Comment: hmm interesting. Are you sure it will return a Sessions object after the update? Usually updates and delete methods are void. Could you try a normal approach by retrieving the object first changing the values then persisting it back through the jpa's '.save` method?

Comment: Updated the code to `void`, still the same issue

Comment: Why are you using `nativeQuery`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- if I do not use `nativeQuery` I get the below error : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepository':

Comment: Which has a chain of "caused by" that probably indicates where your actual problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Using your JPARepsitory try retrieving the object first; updating the values then persisting it back:

In your repository create a method like:

```
@Query(value = "select s From Sessions s where s.topicName = ?1 and s.createdBy=?2")
Sessions findSession(String topicName, String createdBy );
```

Then in your code:

```
Sessions s = repository.findSession("hello", "foo");
s.setTerminatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());

repository.save(s);
```

After that it should persist to the database correctly.

One thing you might want to look at is if Hibernate knows how to handle `LocalDateTime` objects. Ive only seen it still use the `Date` Object natively.

Answer (score -1):

To manipulate data you actually need executeUpdate() rather than executeQuery(). executeQuery() is only meant for SELECT queries (i.e. queries that return a result set).

Comment: the Op  is not running those commands. It is being called behind the scenes. The OP is using `JPARepository` for CRUD operations.

Comment: Yup. I was trying to let him know that engine is firing executeQuery it needs to be executeUpdate and @Modifying, as you commented, makes that but I think it needs more digging why he is getting bean exception.